# circular css menu acting weird

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a circular menu. I found it on this site: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/09/building-a-circular-navigation-with-css-transforms/

But it is acting very weird. I can't press the same button several times. It seems that when i have pressed a button one time i can never press it again. Can anyone see what the problem is?

https://jsfiddle.net/bewsbews/jznqeh5o/1/

it might have to do something with this js code:

```
     (function () {

    var button = document.getElementById('cn-button'),
        wrapper = document.getElementById('cn-wrapper'),
        overlay = document.getElementById('cn-overlay');

    //open and close menu when the button is clicked
    var open = false;
    button.addEventListener('click', handler, false);
    button.addEventListener('focus', handler, false);
    wrapper.addEventListener('click', cnhandle, false);

    function cnhandle(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }

    function handler(e) {
        if (!e) var e = window.event;
        e.stopPropagation();//so that it doesn't trigger click event on document

        if (!open) {
            openNav();
        }
        else {
            closeNav();
        }
    }
    function openNav() {
        open = true;
        button.innerHTML = "-";
        classie.add(overlay, 'on-overlay');
        classie.add(wrapper, 'opened-nav');
    }
    function closeNav() {
        open = false;
        button.innerHTML = "+";
        classie.remove(overlay, 'on-overlay');
        classie.remove(wrapper, 'opened-nav');
    }
    document.addEventListener('click', closeNav);

})();
```

Comment: so you want the navigation to open and close as many times as you click? is that the while center button in the jsfiddle or the outer buttons?

Comment: noo the button works fine. The links around the button is the problem. if you press one and then press another one and then go back again it wont work.

Comment: okay ill have a look for you